# Loop Through Rows in Table to Set Variable (SSIS/VS)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have a list of links in a table that are api calls:

```
RowNumber,Link
1,somelink.net/1
2,somelink.net/2
3,somelink.net/3
```

I want to loop through each row to grab the link value and use it to set a variable (@link) that would be used in the API task.

I have looped through results before but I am hitting a wall. I created a @RowNumber variable I wanted to use in the "Execute SQL Task" that would then be increased + 1 everytime the loop finished until there were no more rows left.

Ideal workflow is:

```
-EXECUTE SQL TASK WHERE ROWNUMBER = @RowNumber to get the @link
-EXECUTE API CALL WITH @link
-ADD + 1 TO @RowNumber
-REPEAT UNTIL ALL ROWS ARE CONSUMED
```

Comment: Did you already try to real your table into an objectr variable and use a SSIS foreach in order to loop through it?

Comment: Nope. I was taking a completely different approach. Have any links you can point me to for an example?

Comment: have alook at the following link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS

Comment: @Tyron78 worked perfectly ... knew it had to be something simple I was missing. much appreciated